# Azure custom domain name with NetworkSolutions DNS

Tags: azure, dns

I'm having trouble setting up my domain purchased from networksolutions.com to azurewebsites.net or cloudapp.net.

Here are some of the resources I'm using, so far with no success. The instructions are varied and I also suspect that network solutions does not allow for the correct settings.

Has any body set up successfully with network solutions?

[Configure custom domain name](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

[Custom DNS website](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/)

---

!!UPDATE!! 
Thanks to the answer.. here are the CORRECT NetworkSolution DNS settings to get you plugged into azurewebsites.net

[image: cname]
[image]

Azure settings...
[image]

Comment: I still need to update this with the settings for the A record.. this only works for www.yoursite.com and not yoursite.com. The links to provide instructions though.

Comment: Can you update the post to show how to configure the A record?

Comment: I noticed that you did not need to put the IP that Azure gives you in the A Record. I really need help with Windows Azure using Network Solutions Domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the DNS Zone file. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725307/network-solution-host-godaddy-registrar) and this [link](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/dns-manager-advanced-tools/).

The exact steps to setup a Custom Domain is as follows

1. Go to DNS Zone file and add a CNAME for domains like www.example.com or mysite.example.com. Add a DNS Record ( C-Record ) - "www" : "mygreateazuresite.azurewebsites.net"
2. Then come to Azure portal, in the Custom Domain Option, put the complete URL [ www.example.com ]
3. The process to set up custom domain for both Azure Websites and Azure Cloud Services are very similar

Comment: This works!! It took a few hours to update but the thing I was missing was your step 2, placing the www.customdomainname.com into the manage domain setting in the azure portal. For reference, everything in the question post is accurate and should work. As of 12-5-2013 we need to upgrade to Shared, or Reserved for azurewebsties.net. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that these settings only work for www.customdomain.com and does not work for customdomain.com. Any more advice?

Answer (score 0):

I have Found a nice step by step tutorial (azure web app + network solutions), same steps but a bit more detailed (including a simple tool to check your domain settings):

http://loldemar.azurewebsites.net/custom-domain-name-in-azure-using-network-solutions/

Basic steps:

- Go to azure web app, go to configure tab, and choose manage domains, from there copy the IP address that is bellow this message (Help for IP Address THE IP ADDRESS TO USE WHEN YOU CONFIGURE A RECORDS)
- Go to network solutions (advanced DNS Settings) in your Add IPAddress on your IP Address A Records (@).

  - The go to cname records and add

awverify.yoursitenamehere.net   7200    awverify.yourazuresitename.azurewebsites.net.
awverify.www.yoursitenamehere.net   7200    awverify.yourazuresitename.azurewebsites.net.
www.yoursitenamehere.net    7200    yourazuresitename.azurewebsites.net.

- Now go back to azure, click again manage domains, and add your domain names (yoursitename.net and www.yoursitename.net)